# Check for presence of div by ID in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I want to do the following inside a rails view:

```
if <Div with ID "X" exists>
  do some stuff
end
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: This looks to be client-side job rather than the back-end's. Can you show where the `div` element is being rendered?

Comment: You need to use javascript.  In jquery you would target the element as:  $("#id_here")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the existence of DOM elements is the client-side's job, if you were to do it by JavaScript you'll have something like this:

```
if(document.getElementById('x')) {
  // ... code
}
```

Also you can embed this JavaScript snippet into your HAML template by using HAML's `:javascript` tag, like so:

```
# template.haml
%div#x

:javascript
    if(document.getElementById('x')) {
      // ... code
    }
```